# Can't get jQuery cycle plugin to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I can't seem to get this plugin to work. I feel like I've tried everything, checked syntax, looked online but I don't see what's wrong with what I have so I must be missing something. I am a beginner so it's possible I'm making a lot of mistakes without realizing it.

Here is the .js file:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
       $(".jumbotron-left").cycle({
       fx: "fade",
       speed: 1500
       });
});
```

here is where I tried to link the script in the header:

```
<head>
<title>adkjfhasldasfljk</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="/scriptt/jquery.cycle.lite.js"></script>
<script src="/scriptt/script.js"></script>
</head>
```

and here is the html for the images I'm trying to fade:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
<div class="jumbotron-left">
    <img src="images/paco.jpg" width="418" height="368"/>
    <img src="images/julie.jpg" width="418" height="368"/>
    <img src="images/tatum.jpg" width="418" height="368"/>
</div>
```

(the other div gets closed off further down)

The images show up but are not fading.

Comment: Open browser console (hit F12) Any errors in there?

Comment: Are you using [Malsup's Cycle Lite](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/lite/)? Are the paths to your script files correct? [Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/e7smw2hr/).

Comment: If you are interested.. [try this one](http://vinayakjadhav.github.io/jR3DCarousel/)